# twint issue time data '2020–04–29 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, date, date-formatting, twint

I faced an issue when I want to scrape data from Twitter configuring `Since` and `Until`.  I use the format like this `'2020-01-01 00:00:00'`:

```
config = twint.Config()
# ...
config.Since = "2020–04–29 00:00:00"
config.Until = "2020–05–29 00:00:00"
twint.run.Search(config)
```

and this error shows to me

`ValueError: time data '2020–04–29 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

This was driving me crazy, but the following works perfectly

```
import datetime
since = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1)
until = datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1)
print(since)
print(until)
```

That gets it into a format TWINT will accept. Then...

```
c.Since = str(since) 
c.Until = str(until)
```

This worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 2):

try with this format
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%ss"

[TimeFormat](https://axibase.com/docs/charts/syntax/date-format.html)

ss: two digit second in minute (00-59).
S: fractional seconds, up to nine (9) digits.